# Function for creating a new line but leaving point in same column

Tags: indentation, line-break

Is there such a function?  It should correspond to pressing `return` and `space` enough times to get back to the old column.  I believe this is known as a linefeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`(emacs) Inserting Text`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html) describes that <kbd>RET</kbd>, by default, exhibits similar behaviour, in that it performs mode-dependent indentation on the new line.

I believe the only built-in mode-independent way to achieve the desired behaviour is by using a combination of <kbd>C-M-o</kbd> (`split-line`; see [`(emacs) Indentation Commands`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html)), followed by <kbd>C-n</kbd> (`next-line`).

The downside of this is that the `split-line` command is not identical to `newline` et al. It will, for example, leave trailing whitespace before point intact when `electric-indent-mode` is enabled, and its prefix argument does not signify repetition, should you wish to insert multiple newlines at once.

Here is a sample wrapper command you could use:

```el
(defun my-newline-and-indent (&optional n)
  "Call `newline' with N, but preserve current column."
  (interactive "*P")
  (let ((col (current-column)))
    (newline n t)
    (indent-to col)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Basil gave a good answer for this question.

Here's another way to do it, albeit a bit crazy. ;-)

```
(defun my-newline-and-indent (&optional n)
  (interactive "*p")
  (picture-mode)
  (picture-open-line n)
  (picture-move-down n)
  (picture-mode-exit 'keep))
```